# Create a Python function out of a JS tree

Tags: javascript, python, function, jstree, multilinestring

I need to create a function from the following bunch of code:

```
jsHelperFunctions = """
function getTreeList(treeId) {
            var $tree = $(treeId);
            var itemsList = [];
            var treeList = $($tree.jstree().get_json($tree, {
                            flat: true
            })).each(function(i, val) {
                            itemsList.push($tree.jstree().get_node(val.id))
            })

            return itemsList;
}

function getItemByItemCode(itemCode, itemsList) {
            return itemsList.filter(val => val.original.account_code == 
itemCode)[0]
}"""
```

and this is the one line of code my supervisor gave me:

```
treeList = driver.execute_script(jsHelperFunctions + """ return 
getTreeList("#tree");""")
```

Tried something like this, but I am not sure about that (first function):

```
def get_tree_list(treeId):
tree = treeId
itemsList = []
treeList = tree.jstree().get_json(tree, flat: true).each(function(i, val)
itemsList.push(tree.jstree().get_node(val.id))
return itemsList
```

Also what is about `val` and the `flat` in Py?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please show us some sample codes that you tried?

Comment: Seems more like a *Do my homework for me* kind of question.

Comment: I have tried something like this but as I said, I am not really familiar with Py and JS as Programming languages. That should be the first function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Solution. Took me a few days...

```
def getTreeList(treeId):
return driver.execute_script(jsHelperFunctions + """ return getTreeList(\""""+ treeId 
+"\");")
```

`treeList = getTreeList("#tree")`

and this...

```
def getItemByCode(itemCode, treeList):
"""
    Returns None if the item code is not found
"""
filtered_iterable =  filter(lambda row : row["original"]["item_code"] == itemCode, 
treeList)
filtered_list = list(filtered_iterable)
if len(filtered_list)  == 0:
    return None     
assert(len(filtered_list) == 1) #item codes must be unique - so something's wrong 
return filtered_list[0]
```